# Is there a way to run the query and inspect the aggregate data without rerunning the query again?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to look at the query result count (and possibly other aggregate data) before deciding to enumerate the result set of a LINQ query.

Almost every LINQ example immediately enumerates the results in a foreach loop.  But I want to inspect the count to determine if I need to loop through each result or not.  Is there a way to run the query and inspect the aggregate data without rerunning the query again?  If I do something like

```
query.Count()
foreach(var item in query) { ... }
```

I suppose it will execute the query twice, but it doesn't need to be re-executed again... only enumerated over the already-returned result set from Count().

When querying a SQL database, it is often very efficient to first run a separate aggregate query and then another query to get the row data if needed.  But if I understand LINQ correctly, it will perform the same operation--same loops and logic locally without any particular optimization--no matter if I get the Count() or do a foreach.  Is there an efficient and/or built-in way to persist the results for multiple operations?

Comment: `var result = query.ToList();  var count = result.Count;  foreach (var item in result) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET, `IEnumerable<T>` sequences are lazy: this means that the underlying logic is executed when and only when you need it. A side effect is that if you need the result twice, the logic is executed twice.

For instance, if the sequence is bound to the results from an SQL database, the SQL query will be executed two times if you first count the number of elements and then list them all.

Some LINQ methods just transform the result you *will* get, without actually getting the results. For instance, `var b = a.Where(a > 0);` won't run the underlying logic, but postpone until you actually need the result.

Other LINQ methods effectively force the logic to be executed. `Count()`, for instance, will force all elements to be loaded in order to count them. `ToArray()` or `ToList()` will do that too, storing the elements in memory for further use.

The approach you are looking for depends entirely on the context.

In general, you may want to store the sequence in memory—for example by using `ToList()`—in order to do multiple operations on it later, such as counting the number of elements and then looping through all of them. On the other hand, there are cases where you will need something else:

- The impact of the underlying logic may be too high in order to load everything in memory, forcing you to search for a smarter solution. Imagine that you are doing database search and you want to show the number of results (say 2 000 000) as well as the first twenty entries. Do you really need to store all 2 000 000 results in memory? Probably not.

  The solution here would be to do a `count` SQL query (that the database engine will be able to optimize), followed by the actual query which gets the first twenty results.

  A similar example is when you get few elements, but it requires many CPU cycles to get a single element. Sometimes, shortcuts can be used to short-circuit the complex work when all you need is to count the elements.
- Or the opposite may happen: the underlying logic and the amount of data is too small to actually care. Imagine that you are dealing with characters within `A-Za-z` range. Is it really necessary to do a `ToList()`? Wouldn't it be easier to count, and then to loop through the characters separately?
- Sometimes, it won't even be possible to store all elements in memory. For instance, what if you have an infinite sequence (such as the lines flushed from a log file which is constantly written to)?

> But if I understand LINQ correctly, it will perform the same operation--same loops and logic locally without any particular optimization--no matter if I get the Count() or do a foreach.

This depends entirely on the ORM you use. When you create your LINQ query, such as:

```cs
var count = this.SequenceFromDatabase
    .Where(product => product.Price > 0)
    .Count();

foreach (var product in this.SequenceFromDatabase.Take(10))
{
    ...
}
```

some (if not most) ORMs will actually translate this into:

```sql
select count(1) from [Schema].[Table] where [Price] > 0

select top 10 [Name], [Price], [Availability] from [Schema].[Table]
```

Given that the actual translation from LINQ to SQL queries depends on the ORMs and the actual LINQ code you write, it is essential to keep an eye on the SQL queries being executed. Many ORMs have the ability to trace the SQL queries, and some SQL engines allow you to profile the queries as well.